# Can't call keyup function of js object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is code
http://jsfiddle.net/8ZzER/26/

I try to call the function bound to `keyup` but `keyPres` variable is null

**HTML**

```
<input id="text" name="text" type="text" onkeyup="alert('Boom')"  
       value="Key up here"/>
<input type="button" id="fire" value="fire" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("fire").onclick=function()
{
    var textElement = document.getElementById("fire");
    var keyPres= textElement.onkeyup;
    keyPres.call();
}
```

Comment: In the future, please put your code *in the question*, not on an external site. I have copied it here.

Answer (score 3):

Your handler is on the element with "id" value "text", but your code looks for "fire".

```
<input id="text" name="text" type="text" onkeyup="alert('Boom')"  
       value="Key up here"/>
<input type="button" id="fire" value="fire" />
```

The handler should look like:

```
// says "fire" in your jsFiddle
var textElement = document.getElementById("text"); 
var keyPres= textElement.onkeyup;
keyPres.call();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are assigning `textElement` to your button (`fire`) and not your text box.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZzER/29/